# src refspec main does not match any: failed to push some refs to git (for existing project)

Tags: git, gitlab

I need to upload an existing project to my own repository

Preconditions:

- I have downloaded a new project from a zip file
- I have created a new project on my own git repo

Steps:

I followed the given instruction from the git:

```
git init
git remote add origin https://...`  
git branch -M main
git push -uf origin main
```

Error:

> error: src refspec main does not match any
> error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gitlab.com/../...-main.git'

Additional info:

- I have established the `ssh` connection with my repository and successfully used git on the other projects.
- I also was trying the option with `git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:..../...-main.git` but received the same result

---

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

double-check you have the remote added with

```
git remote -v
```

you should see your remote repository url, then try

```
git fetch origin main
```

instead of pushing.

you can push once do the fetching.